# python - matplotlib how to set every subplot x label, y label together

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't want any subplot's label. Right now, I have to set every subplot axes one by one. Any way to set them all together.

```
f, ((ax1, ax2),(ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax1.set_ylabel('')
ax1.set_ylabel('')
ax2.set_ylabel('')
ax2.set_ylabel('')
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a loop over all axes:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2)
for ax in axarr.flat:
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    ax.set_ylabel('')
```

or even shorter:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2)
for ax in axarr.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
```

Comment: thanks! any different between using axarr or more complicated ((ax1, ax2),(ax3, ax4))?

Comment: `((ax1, ax2),(ax3, ax4))` is just the unpacked version of axarr. `ax1=ax[0, 0]` and so on